# SeekBar and media player in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-seekbar

I have a simple player and recorder. Everything works great but have one problem. I want to add seek bar to see progress in playing record and use this seek bar to set the place from the player should play. I have onProgress but with no effect. This is the code:

```
package com.example.recorder;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener
{
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "AudioRecordTest";
    private static String mFileName = null;
    private SeekBar seekBar;
    private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
    private Button startRecord, startPlaying, stopPlaying;
    private MediaPlayer   mPlayer = null;

    private void onRecord(boolean start) {
        if (start) {
            startRecording();
        } else {
            stopRecording();
        }
    }


    
    private void startPlaying() {
        if(mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mPlayer.pause();
        } else if(mPlayer != null){
            mPlayer.start();
        }else{
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            
            mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);
            mPlayer.prepare();
            mPlayer.start();
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }
        }
    
    }

    private void stopPlaying() {
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
        startPlaying.setText("Start playing");
    }

    private void pausePlaying(){
        if(mPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mPlayer.pause();
        } else {
          mPlayer.start();
        }
    }
    
    private void startRecording() {
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }

        mRecorder.start();
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;
    }



    public MainActivity() {
        mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        mFileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        startPlaying = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStartPlay);
        stopPlaying = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStopPlaying);
        startRecord = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStartRecord);
        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        
        startRecord.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            boolean mStartRecording = true;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onRecord(mStartRecording);
                if (mStartRecording) {
                    startRecord.setText("Stop recording");
                } else {
                    startRecord.setText("Start recording");
                }
                mStartRecording = !mStartRecording;
                
            }
        });  
        
        
        startPlaying.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            boolean mStartPlaying = true;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //onPlay(mStartPlaying);
                startPlaying();
                if (mStartPlaying) {
                    startPlaying.setText("Stop playing");
                } else {
                    startPlaying.setText("Start playing");
                }
                mStartPlaying = !mStartPlaying;
            }
        });
        
        stopPlaying.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            boolean mStartPlaying = true;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 stopPlaying();
                
            }
        });
        
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mRecorder != null) {
            mRecorder.release();
            mRecorder = null;
        }

        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {
        if(fromUser){
            mPlayer.seekTo(progress); 
            seekBar.setProgress(progress);
            }
            else{
             // the event was fired from code and you shouldn't call player.seekTo()
            }
        
    }



    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }



    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to use seek bar to see progress and set place from the record should play?

Comment: remove ` seekBar.setProgress(progress);` from `onProgressChanged()` its redundent.

Comment: your comment doesn't change anything :)

Comment: ya i just found, its useless. And its just suggestion not answer :)

Answer (score 176, accepted):

To create a 'connection' between `SeekBar` and `MediaPlayer` you need first to get your current recording max duration and set it to your seek bar.

```
mSeekBar.setMax(mFileDuration/1000); // where mFileDuration is mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
```

After you initialise your `MediaPlayer` and for example press play button, you should create handler and post runnable so you can update your `SeekBar` (in the `UI thread` itself) with the current position of your `MediaPlayer` like this :

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
//Make sure you update Seekbar on UI thread
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(mMediaPlayer != null){
            int mCurrentPosition = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
            mSeekBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
        }
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
});
```

and update that value every second.

If you need to update the `MediaPlayer`'s position while user drag your `SeekBar` you should add `OnSeekBarChangeListener` to your `SeekBar` and do it there :

```
        mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {                
                if(mMediaPlayer != null && fromUser){
                    mMediaPlayer.seekTo(progress * 1000);
                }
            }
    });
```

And that should do the trick! : )

**EDIT:**
One thing which I've noticed in your code, don't do :

```
public MainActivity() {
    mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    mFileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";
}
```

make all initialisations in your `onCreate();` , do not create constructors of your `Activity`.

Comment: Just to have some conceptual understanding, why not create constructor and make initialization in `onCreate`? you sounds that constructor will be glitchy?

Comment: yes, best method. just a note: if you do int mCurrentPosition = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000; then you probably have to also do this : mSeekBar.setMax(mFileDuration / 1000);

Comment: what does he mean when he says //Make sure you update Seekbar on UI thread?? dont i just throw his handler in onCreateView? and itll update every second?

Comment: I tried this but when I drag the seek bar its playing from beginning of the song but not from that position??

Comment: Can any one answer to my comment?

Comment: @ShylendraMadda any piece of code where I can see what is your problem or how are you using it?

Comment: @hardartcore See y question here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31981959/android-media-player-seekbar-play-from-stopped-position

Comment: You should mind if the loopers queue not full of YOUR other messages which may introduce latency for such sensitive cases.

Comment: it should be `mSeekBar.setMax(mFileDuration/1000);`

Comment: In my case it is updating seekbar. Any help?

Comment: This line really save me from lagging issue before `if(mMediaPlayer != null && fromUser)` thank you so much +1

Comment: How would `MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {` need to be changed so this would work in a RecyclerViewAdapter for a Fragment instead of an activity?

Comment: Can't stress enough the importance of validating if the progressChange was triggered by the user. Otherwise, every time you call setProgress, the onProgressChanged callback will be invoked every second, resetting the seek position. Thank you!

Comment: Don't understand why you are dividing the current position with 1000. I have tried it and it does not work properly because the file duration set above goes usually in thousandths of values(ms). I removed the division and then it worked properly.

Comment: also remember to remove runnable when media player is paused or end of audio file is reached, or else the runnable will keep running, realized this because i logged every time the runnable ran, and got a ton of logs. thanks for the solution though, other than that it works pretty well

Answer (score 14):

I've used this tutorial with success, it's really simple to understand:
[www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/)

This is the interesting part:

```
/**
 * Update timer on seekbar
 * */
public void updateProgressBar() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
}  

/**
 * Background Runnable thread
 * */
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
           long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

           // Displaying Total Duration time
           songTotalDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
           // Displaying time completed playing
           songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

           // Updating progress bar
           int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
           //Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
           songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);

           // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
           mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
       }
    };

/**
 *
 * */
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {

}

/**
 * When user starts moving the progress handler
 * */
@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // remove message Handler from updating progress bar
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
}

/**
 * When user stops moving the progress hanlder
 * */
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    int totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
    int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), totalDuration);

    // forward or backward to certain seconds
    mp.seekTo(currentPosition);

    // update timer progress again
    updateProgressBar();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

After you initialize your `MediaPlayer` and `SeekBar`, you can do this :

```
 Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mSeekBar.setProgress(mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
        }
    },0,1000);
```

This updates `SeekBar` every second(1000ms)

And for updating `MediaPlayer`, if user drag `SeekBar`, you must add `OnSeekBarChangeListener` to your `SeekBar` :

```
mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
            mMediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
```

HAPPY CODING!!!

Answer (score 3):

Code in Kotlin:

```
var updateSongTime = object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                val getCurrent = mediaPlayer?.currentPosition
                startTimeText?.setText(String.format("%d:%d",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(getCurrent?.toLong() as Long),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(getCurrent?.toLong()) -
                                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(getCurrent?.toLong()))))
                seekBar?.setProgress(getCurrent?.toInt() as Int)
                Handler().postDelayed(this, 1000)
            }
        }
```

For changing media player audio file every second

If user drags the seek bar then following code snippet can be use

```html
Statified.seekBar?.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar, i: Int, b: Boolean) {
                if(b && Statified.mediaPlayer != null){
                    Statified.mediaPlayer?.seekTo(i)
                }

            }
            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {}
            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {}
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

check this, you should give arguments in msecs, Dont just send `progress` to [seekTo(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#seekTo%28int%29)

and also check this [getCurrentPostion()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#getCurrentPosition%28%29) and [getDuration()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#getDuration%28%29).

You can do some calcuations, ie., convert `progress` in msec like `msce = (progress/100)*getDuration()` then do `seekTo(msec)`

Or else i have an easy idea, you don't need to change any code anywer else just add `seekBar.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration())` once your media player is prepared.

and here is link exactly what you want [seek bar update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242918/android-media-player-and-seekbar-sync-issue)

Answer (score 2):

The below code worked for me.

I've created a method for seekbar

```
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    mp.start();
     getDurationTimer();
    getSeekBarStatus();


}
//Creating duration time method
public void getDurationTimer(){
    final long minutes=(mSongDuration/1000)/60;
    final int seconds= (int) ((mSongDuration/1000)%60);
    SongMaxLength.setText(minutes+ ":"+seconds);


}



 //creating a method for seekBar progress
public void getSeekBarStatus(){

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // mp is your MediaPlayer
            // progress is your ProgressBar

            int currentPosition = 0;
            int total = mp.getDuration();
            seekBar.setMax(total);
            while (mp != null && currentPosition < total) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return;
                }
                seekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);

            }
        }
    }).start();





    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        int progress=0;

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(final SeekBar seekBar, int ProgressValue, boolean fromUser) {
            if (fromUser) {
                mp.seekTo(ProgressValue);//if user drags the seekbar, it gets the position and updates in textView.
            }
            final long mMinutes=(ProgressValue/1000)/60;//converting into minutes
            final int mSeconds=((ProgressValue/1000)%60);//converting into seconds
            SongProgress.setText(mMinutes+":"+mSeconds);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
}
```

SongProgress and SongMaxLength are the TextView to show song duration and song length.

Answer (score 2):

My code snippet:

```
public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "PlayerActivity";
private ActivityPlayerBinding binding;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private boolean playingAudio = false;
Runnable runnable;
Handler handler;


 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityPlayerBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(
            new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                    .build()
    );

    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(songUrl);
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mp -> {
        binding.playBtn.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_pause));
        binding.seekbarPlayer.setMax(mp.getDuration());
        mediaPlayer.start();
        playingAudio = true;
        updateSeekbar();
    });

    mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener((mp, percent) -> {
        double ratio = percent / 100.0;
        int bufferingLevel = (int) (mp.getDuration() * ratio);
        binding.seekbarPlayer.setSecondaryProgress(bufferingLevel);
    });

    binding.seekbarPlayer.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChangeListener);

}

    private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarChangeListener = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        if (fromUser) {
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
            seekBar.setProgress(progress);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
};
    private void updateSeekbar() {
    try {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            int currentPos = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            binding.seekbarPlayer.setProgress(currentPos);
            runnable = this::updateSeekbar;
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "updateSeekbar: " + e.getMessage());
    }  
  }
}
```

Comment: hi buddy, if(fromUser), this is really help me. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int  pos  = 0;
    yourSeekBar.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration());
```

After You start Your `MediaPlayer` i.e `mplayer.start()`

#### Try this code

```
while(mPlayer!=null){
         try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                pos  = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            }  catch (Exception e) {
                //show exception in LogCat
            }
            yourSeekBar.setProgress(pos);

   }
```

Before you added this code you have to create `xml` resource for `SeekBar` and use it in Your `Activity` class of ur `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
seekbarPlayer.setMax(mp.getDuration());
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(mp != null){
            seekbarPlayer.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());
        }
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the answer [**hardartcore**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17171025/10807406) that worked for me with a small change and did not work before the change:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
MusicPlayer.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
          if(player != null){
               int mCurrentPosition = player.getCurrentPosition();//clear ' /1000 '
               seekBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
          }
          mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
      }
});



seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
          if(player != null && fromUser){
              player.seekTo(progress); // clear ' * 1000  '
          }
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To add on to @hardartcore's answer.

1. Instead of calling postDelayed on a Handler, the best approach would be to get callbacks from the `MediaPlayer` during play-back and then accordingly update the seekBar with the progress.
2. Also, pause your `MediaPlayer` at `onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)` of the `OnSeekBarChangeListener` and then re-start it on `onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on previous statements, for better performance, you can also add an if condition

```
if (player.isPlaying() {
    handler.postDelayed(..., 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MediaPlayer mplayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //You create MediaPlayer variable ==> set the path and start the audio.

    mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.example);
    mplayer.start();

            //Find the seek bar by Id (which you have to create in layout)
            // Set seekBar max with length of audio
           // You need a Timer variable to set progress with position of audio

    final SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekBar.setMax(mplayer.getDuration());

    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    seekBar.setProgress(mplayer.getCurrentPosition());
                }
            }, 0, 1000);


            seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            // Update the progress depending on seek bar
                    mplayer.seekTo(progress);

                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: You may want to add some context to the code in your solution to help others understand the solution more efficiently.