# How do i update Seekbar mp3 progress every second with a thread?(code/pics included) Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-seekbar

Im trying to get the seekbar to update and show progress whenever I play an mp3 with mediaPlayer.  Music plays fine everytime, seekbar will always snap to 0 position when mp3 is playing.

I was trying to follow this answer but it just wont work... [SeekBar and media player in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168215/seekbar-and-media-player-in-android)

I have this code in main activity

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (Assets.mediaPlayer != null) {
                int mCurrentPosition = Assets.mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                if(OnionFragment.seekBar!= null) {
                    OnionFragment.seekBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
                }
            }
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    });
```

in OnionFragment I have

```
public static SeekBar seekBar;
seekBar = (SeekBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
```

and in OnionFragments onclick  (the play button)I have

```
Assets.playMusicFile(MainActivity.items.get(MainActivity.selectedItem).getSongId(), true);
                if(Assets.mediaPlayer!=null) {
                    seekBar.setMax(Assets.mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                }
```

OnionFragment is loaded into MainActivity right away and looks like this

[image]
P.S. If anyone has extra time, how do i change size of seekbar ball and color

Comment: inside run method add some Log.d calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
seekBar.setMax(Assets.mediaPlayer.getDuration());
```

to

```
seekBar.setMax(Assets.mediaPlayer.getDuration()/1000);
```