# How to move current time position from 0.00 sec when played

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Here is the java file:

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AudioPlayer extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView mIvPlayControl;
    TextView mTvTotalDuration;
    TextView mTvCurrentPosition;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.music_player2);

        mIvPlayControl= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_play);
        mTvTotalDuration= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_total);
        mTvCurrentPosition= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_progress);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(AudioPlayer.this, R.raw.sleep_away);
        int mCurrentPosition=mp.getCurrentPosition();
        int duration=mp.getDuration(); // miliseconds time
        //convert into seconds
        duration=duration/1000;
        mCurrentPosition=mp.getCurrentPosition()/1000;
        Log.e("value","value: "+duration);
        mTvTotalDuration.setText(String.valueOf(duration));
        mTvCurrentPosition.setText(String.valueOf(mCurrentPosition));

        mIvPlayControl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.pause();
                    mIvPlayControl.setImageResource(R.mipmap.play_small);

                } else {
                    mp.start();
                    mIvPlayControl.setImageResource(R.mipmap.pause_small);
                }

            }
        });
```

And here is the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_progress"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0.00"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_play"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/play_small"

            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_total"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="0.00"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

How do i move the beginning time 0 and onwards when played? Do i have to add seek bar to get moving time? Can somebody please help here? The song can be played but timer doesn't work. And more details or questions are in the comments.

Comment: do you want to create 'connection' between SeekBar and MediaPlayer?

Comment: No. I just want to move its current position like when i press play its stays on 0.00 but the song is still playing. So all i want to know how to change time from 0.00 and onwards when played.

Comment: I think this answer will help you:
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/17171025/6862286](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17171025/6862286)

Comment: Its all about seek bar. I didn't find any answers.

Comment: can you please elaborate your question or what you want to do??

Comment: I created a simple audio player. When i click play, the song starts playing but timer doesn't . It shows only beginning and end time.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `mTvCurrentPlayTime` is TesxtView representing current play-time on the screen then you can use following code to update the view:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
//Make sure you update TextView on UI thread
AudioPlayer.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(mp!= null){
            int mCurrentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
            mTvCurrentPosition.setText(String.valueOf(mCurrentPosition));
        }
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there any way i can post long reply cause i got to show you the coding,

Comment: @ShubhangAgarwal It is better if you edit your question and add your code. It will be helpful to others to help you resolve your issue.

Comment: Its been a day since i edited a question. Will you please help here?

Comment: @ShubhangAgarwal I have updated my answer. Please put this code after you set listener and test it. Let me know if any issue.

Comment: I am getting error on 2nd line invalid method declaration; return type required.