# Seekbar Updating whole song again and again

Tags: android, android-seekbar

Hello i want to update seekbar smoothly which update on every second, so i have created a method using timer which update seekbar on every second but its updating the song again nd again on every second i have searched on everywhere but not getting solution i don't want to use any handler i want to fix using this method

```
 private  void updateseekbar() {


    seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());

     new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
       @Override
       public void run() {

                   seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

       }
   },1000,1000);
```

and here i have implemente the method when song start

```
  public void play(View v) {

    if (mediaPlayer == null) {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, songlist.get(index));
        mediaPlayer.start();
        updateseekbar();
        imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_btn_play_pressed);
    } else if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_btn_pause);
    } else if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
        imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_btn_play_pressed);



    }
```

here is my full code

```
private SeekBar seekBar;
TextView startduration,totalduration;
ImageView imageview, forwardd, backword, next, previous;
ArrayList<Integer> songlist = new ArrayList<>();
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
int seektime = 5000;
int index = 0;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    forwardd = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.forwardd);
    backword = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backword);
    next = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.next);
    previous = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.previous);
    startduration= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startduration);
    totalduration= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalduration);


    songlist.add(R.raw.diljaniya);
    songlist.add(R.raw.stand);
    songlist.add(R.raw.haledil);
    songlist.add(R.raw.myname);
    songlist.add(R.raw.fiftyways);
    songlist.add(R.raw.desiboys);

    previous = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.previous);

 seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
     @Override
     public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {

         seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
         mediaPlayer.seekTo(i);


     }

     @Override
     public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

     }

     @Override
     public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

     }
 });

    forwardd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                int med = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                if (med <= mediaPlayer.getDuration()) {
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(med + seektime);
                    seekBar.setProgress(med+seektime);


                }
            } else {

            }
        }
    });
    backword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                int med = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                if (med - seektime >= 0) {
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(med - seektime);
                    seekBar.setProgress(med-seektime);
                } else {
                }
            } else {
            }
        }
    });
}

public void play(View v) {

    if (mediaPlayer == null) {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, songlist.get(index));
        mediaPlayer.start();
        updateseekbar();
        imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_btn_play_pressed);
    } else if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_btn_pause);
    } else if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
        imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_btn_play_pressed);



    }

}

public void previouss(View v) {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
    }

    if (index < songlist.size() - 1) {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, songlist.get(index));
        mediaPlayer.start();
        seekBar.setProgress(0);
    } else {
        index = 0;
        return;
    }
    index++;
}

public void next(View v) {

    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
    }
    if (index < songlist.size()) {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, songlist.get(index));
        mediaPlayer.start();
        seekBar.setProgress(0);
    } else {
        index = 0;
        return;
    }
    index++;
}


private  void updateseekbar() {


    seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());

     new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
       @Override
       public void run() {

                   seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

       }
   },1000,1000);

}








}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SeekBar and media player in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168215/seekbar-and-media-player-in-android)

Comment: i have updated the question with full code

Comment: no its not duplicate

Comment: `"but its updating the song again nd again on every second"`, what does it mean?

Comment: it mean its updating the music on everysecond like looping

Comment: i have no idea what you are talking about, sorry, `"updating the music"` how updating?

Comment: just guide me how to update the seekbar when music plays my problem will be solved using timer only

Comment: simply use `setProgress` method in one second interval

Comment: see log cat 
10-17 11:39:43.271 5266-5266/abc.myapp.input.mediaseekbar V/MediaPlayer-JNI: getCurrentPosition: 5907 (msec)
10-17 11:39:43.271 5266-5277/abc.myapp.input.mediaseekbar V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=6, ext1=0, ext2=0
10-17 11:39:43.281 5266-5277/abc.myapp.input.mediaseekbar V/MediaPlayer: Received MEDIA_STARTED
10-17 11:39:43.281 5266-5277/abc.myapp.input.mediaseekbar V/MediaPlayer: callback application
V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
10-17 11:39:43.281 5266-5266/abc.myapp.input.mediaseekbar V/MediaPlayer-JNI: getCurrentPosition: 5042 (msec)

Comment: i have just removed  media.seekto(i) from  public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) then its working fine but then how to update progress change when user drag seekbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare Timer as global member variables like this;

```
Timer timer=new Timer();
```

Update the song inside updateseekbar method like this

```
  private void updateseekbar(Boolean songPlay) {
    if(songPlay){
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

            }
        },1000,1000);
        handler.postDelayed(runnable,0);
    }else {
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
    }
}
```

Update seekBar while play the song like this

```
updateseekbar(true);
```

Stop the seekBar update like this

```
updateseekbar(false);
```

Comment: i dont want use handler at this time my task is to use timer, its working fine with timer, but when i put media.seekto(i) in progress change seekbar its updating the music like looping

Comment: when you are using media.seekto(i) you need to stop the timer from updating the dialog.because getCurrentPosition() will be different.

Comment: how to stop timer in progress change?

Comment: i did this and it's working like charm if(b == true) {
               mediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
            }} thankyou for giving me suggestion your answer is  accepted