# How to implement AudioTrack, using seekbar?

Tags: android, mp3, seekbar, audiotrack

I am making Android MP3 player app using AudioTrack. I must not use MediaPlayer in any case, and I use 16bit mono channel and 44100Hz.
**I heard that `seekTo()` method can be implemented using `RandomAccessFile` class**
But I don't know that well in detail. Please Help me.

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17171025/5110595)

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's not too late, but I can give you a few hints.
For playing the audio track you will need to use `MediaExtractor` (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor)
When you play the track you can get the sample time using `extractor.getSampleTime()`, and then just send the progress to the seekBar: `seekBar.setProgress((int) extractor.getSampleTime() / 1000);`