# Seekbar not updating

Tags: android, seekbar

I made this method and put it inside my onCreate method but the seekBar is still not moving. Help.

```
public void changeSeekbar() {

    if(mySong.isPlaying()) {
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mySeekBar.setMax(mySong.getDuration());
                x = mySong.getCurrentPosition();
                mySeekBar.setProgress(x);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 50);
                changeSeekbar();
            }
        };

    }
}
```

Comment: please refer this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17171025/4748607)

Comment: you only set the runnable variable, you didn't call it. and you will need to update of the seekbar is done on UI thread.