# MediaPlayer stops audio sound

Tags: android, seekbar

When I add the seekTo function inside onProgressChanged a voice interrupt happens after every seekbar jump. How can I prevent this?

```
 final SeekBar seekbar2 = findViewById(R.id.ScrubSeekBar);
   seekbar2.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
   seekbar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

          mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
       }

       @Override
       public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

       }
   });
    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            seekbar2.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
        }
    },0,1000);
}
```

Comment: check this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168215/seekbar-and-media-player-in-android"...